# FIR filters always linear?

Tags: filters

Are Finite Impulse Response filters always linear? I looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_filter and its says that if a filter does not obey linearity, it is non-linear filter. Thats understood? But does does linearity has to do with the length of impulse response?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, FIR filters are linear.  No, the length of the impulse response does not have anything to do with whether it is linear or not.  For instance, IIR filters are also linear.

Linearity is determined by whether the filter obeys the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle), nothing else.  So, FIR and IIR filters are linear, [median filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter) are not.

EDIT: Technically Dilip is correct.  Finite and infinite impulse response filters can be non-linear if their impulse responses incorporate non-linear operations, such as squaring.  I was going by the "industry" meaning of FIR and IIR, which are linear because they only use multiplication and adding, but in the mathematical sense FIR and IIR filters can be non-linear.

Comment: which means FIR filters cannot be non-linear….right?

Comment: That is correct.  They are always linear.

Comment: sometimes people confuse *"phase linear"* with *"linear"*.  two different things.

Comment: So FIR filter can either have a linear or non-linear phase response. So the take home should be that there is no need to say a "linear FIR filter" since its understood.

Comment: in my opinion, yes.  but Dilip disagrees.  and he has a lot higher rep than me.

Comment: This means that there are two different notions of linearity. One in terms of IMPULSE RESPONSE of filter. Second is terms of PHASE RESPONSE. So when we say "linear FIR filter", we are referring to the phase response  of an FIR filter whose impulse response satisfies linearity. Is this correct?

Comment: There is some ambiguity in the terminology.  But yes, since FIR filters are generally linear (though they don't have to be, as Dilip pointed out), usually when people talk about linear FIR filters they are talking about the phase response.

Answer (score 2):

No! FIR filters are NOT always linear phase.  The acronym 'FIR" only tells you that the impulse response is finite in duration, nothing more and nothing less. So called "minimum phase" FIR filters are not linear phase.  (A tapped-delay line, lowpass, FIR filter whose coefficients are [0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.55] has a finite duration impulse response but it's NOT linear phase.) Also, phase linearity does NOT depend on the length of an FIR filter's impulse response.  FIR filters using real-valued coefficients have linear phase if those coefficient values are exactly symmetrical.  FIR differentiators & Hilbert transformers using real-valued coefficients have linear phase if those coefficient values are exactly antisymmetrical.

Comment: I think you might have read the question too quickly. It's not about linear phase but general linearity.